# Form fields not rendering using iTextSharp for conversion to pdf from aspx page

Tags: c#, itext, xmlworker

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBasic" Visible="true" 
 Checked='<%# Eval("BasicProgram")%>' runat="server" />
```

In the above aspx page, I have form fields such as check boxes. I am using iTextsharp and XML Worker to convert the aspx page HTML content to PDF. However the check box is not visible in the pdf file generated. Any suggestions please.

Comment: You are not telling us if you're using `HTMLWorker` or XML Worker. Whatever you're using: HTML form fields are not supported. However, if you are using XML Worker, you can implement form fields by adding tags to the `TagProcessor` (that requires a couple of days extra programming work).

Comment: XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pdfWrite, pdfDoc, sr);

Comment: I've updated your question. It is now clear that you're using XML Worker. Form fields aren't supported by XML Worker, but if you are proficient in iText, you could implement `TagProcessor` classes for the fields you need.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do it. iTextsharp don't like <input type=checkbox>. I want to use any other control like label and display an image as checked or unchecked based on input value.

Comment: No, there is no simpler way to do it.

Comment: I want to use two checkbox images, checked and unchecked using img src tag. Based on true or false value from database i want to show one of them on the page using jquery. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen to use images instead of checkboxes. I am using two images one for checked and other for unchecked and showing them based on condition.